# Checking if username already exists in database before registering

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to add functionality to **check the entered username and see if it exists in the MySql database before the user is successfully registered**. I've tried looking at other similar questions and but because I lack the experience I cannot seem to implement it properly in my code.

Here's what I have so far:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string user = tbUser.Text;
    string pass = tbPass.Text;
    string email = tbEmail.Text;

    if (tbUser.Text == "" || tbPass.Text == "" || tbEmail.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill out all fields.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    else {

        bool exists = false;
        string checkuser = $"SELECT COUNT(*) from users where name = {user}";

       try
        {
            if (OpenConnection())
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(checkuser, conn);

                try
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", tbUser.Text);
                    exists = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
                if (exists)
                    MessageBox.Show("Username already exists.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                else
                {
                    Register(user, pass, email);
                    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Registered!");
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

}

public bool Register(string user, string pass, string email)
{
    string register = $"INSERT INTO users (name, password, email) VALUES('{user}', '{pass}', '{email}');";

    try
    {
        if (OpenConnection()) 
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(register, conn);

            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            conn.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        conn.Close();
        return false;
    }
}

private bool OpenConnection()
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        return true;
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        switch (ex.Number)
        {
            case 0:
                MessageBox.Show("Connection to the server failed.");
                break;
            case 1045:
                MessageBox.Show("Database username or password is incorrect.");
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't work in registering the user & neither does it work in checking if the username exists. Would appreciate any help in pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: In your register function, you forgot to add values for your input parameters. And you don't need to use `'` when using `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: What if user B inserts while user A is checking?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax, as far as I know, to declare a parameter in a command text isn't `{user}` but `@user`.

So this line of code of yours

```
string checkuser = $"SELECT COUNT(*) from users where name = {user}";
```

Should be

```
string checkuser = $"SELECT COUNT(*) from users where name = @user";
```

And the "@user" must correspond to the parameters name you are adding.

You falsly call the parameter `name` instead of `user` on this line

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", tbUser.Text);
```

So it should look like this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", tbUser.Text);
```

As @Transcendent already mentioned in the comments in your `Register` method you never acutally add the 3 parameters used in the command text, to your parameters collections so those line are simply missing

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", tbUser.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pass", tbPass.Text); //this line assumes there is a textbox called tbPass
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", tbEmail.Text); //this line assumes there is a textbox called tbEmail
```